# Can I setup terminal in Ubuntu to tell me what branch I am in?

Tags: git, ubuntu

Wasn't sure whether this was for here or Superuser, opted for here but will move if neccessary.

Can I setup terminal on Ubuntu to display the branch name when in a Git repository? On Git Bash for Windows, [this happens automatically](http://msysgit.github.io/img/gw1.png), and the same functionality would be really handy on Ubuntu, does it exist? Is there some command I can enter to turn this functionality on?

Thanks

Comment: Look for PS1 bash prompt for git https://www.google.com/search?q=git+bash+ps1

Comment: There are also oh-my-zsh themes that include that information.  So depends on your shell and what else you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this by adding the following to my ~/.bashrc file:

```
function parse_git_branch {
   git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\[\1\]/'
} 

function proml {
   local BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
   local DEFAULT="\[\033[0m\]" 
   PS1="\u@\h$BLUE\$(parse_git_branch)$DEFAULT-> \w\n\$ "
}
proml
```

This gives me the following invite:

```
[myusername@mymachinename [branch_name] current_folder]$
```

I'm not expert in linux though, there may be better ways to do this...

Comment: This looks good to me, although I am not an expert in Linux also, thanks very much :)

Comment: Instead of `git branch --no-color` and editing with `sed`, you might try `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` to save one sub-process.  (Keep the redirect for the not-in-a-repo case.)  Since you're adding brackets you may still want some extra tweaks as well, using the exit status to decide whether to add `[]`.